# Update a query by an item selected from a list - Double Click Event

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form called `ConsultaInfo` which display a list (`LNome`) of all partners name and I want to run a query that will bring back to the same form all the rest of information from the selected partner name from the that list.

[image]

My intention is when I double click the partner name, a query (`ConsultaSocio`) will be ran bringing all the other personal information from the selected partner from the Table `Socios` and then these information will be displayed on the right side of the same form.

Therefore, I would like to know how can I accomplish that.

Comment: Please share with us the query (ConsultaSocio) and the vba code that you have so far.

Comment: Bind form to query, apply filter to form. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing this, all of which assuming that in addition to the name being displayed in the list box, there is also an ID field.

If the form is bound to the query, then you can use the `.RecordsetClone` to find the matching record and then set the Form's position:

```
Private Sub lstName_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    Me.RecordsetClone.FindFirst "ID=" & Me!lstName
    Me.Bookmark = Me.RecordsetClone.Bookmark
sExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Exit Sub
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "ConsultaInfo!lstName_DblClick", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume sExit
End Sub
```

Another option is to change the Form's RecordSource property to only have that record:

```
Private Sub lstName_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    Me.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM Socio WHERE ID=" & Me!lstName
sExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Exit Sub
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "ConsultaInfo!lstName_DblClick", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume sExit
End Sub
```

Regards,

Comment: When your refer to ID field you mean the primary key?

Comment: Correct - nearly always an Autonumber.